# Is it possible to call a CUDA CUBLAS function from a global or device function

Tags: cuda, cublas

I'm trying to parallelize an existing application, I have most of the application parallelized and running on the GPU, I'm having issues migrating one function to the GPU

The function uses a  function dtrsv which part of the blas library,see below.

```
void dtrsv_call_N(double* B, double* A, int* n, int* lda, int* incx) {
  F77_CALL(dtrsv)("L","T","N", n, B, lda, A, incx);
}
```

I've been able to call the equivalent cuda/cublas function as per below,and the results produced are equivalent to the fortran dtrsv sub routine.

```
status = cublasDtrsv(handle,CUBLAS_FILL_MODE_LOWER,CUBLAS_OP_T,CUBLAS_DIAG_NON_UNIT, x, dev_m1, x, dev_m2, c);

if (status != CUBLAS_STATUS_SUCCESS) {
        printf ( "!!!! kernel execution error.\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
```

My problem is that I need to be able to call cublasDtrsv from a device or global function, like below,

```
__global__ void Dtrsv__cm2(cublasHandle_t handle,cublasFillMode_t uplo,cublasOperation_t trans, cublasDiagType_t diag,int n, const double *A, int lda, double *x, int incx){
    cublasDtrsv(handle,uplo,trans,diag, n, A, lda, x, incx);
}
```

In cuda 4.0 if I try to compile the below I get the below error, does anyone know if there is a means by which cublas functions can be called from a `__device__` or `__global__` function?

> error: calling a host `function("cublasDtrsv_v2")` from a `__device__`/`__global__` `function("Dtrsv__dev")` is not allowed

Comment: no this isn't not possible. Cublas is a host api and library.

Comment: Thanks very much for the quick answer,  Does anyone know if there is an equivalent which can be called from a device function or a global function ?

Answer (score 6):

CUDA Toolkit 5.0 introduced a device linker that can link device object files compiled separately. I believe, CUBLAS functions from CUDA Toolkit 5.0 can now be called from device functions (but I only reviewed the headers, I have no experience using CUBLAS).

Comment: I can compile the CU file that references the CUBLAS from device code, I'm trying to figure out how to link it :)

Comment: I don't understand how this can possibly ever work. The CUBLAS libraries are supplied as IA32/x86_64 binary only libraries, and internally the routines call host side runtime API functions, launch kernels. How could such code ever run the GPU?

Comment: @talonmies Separate compilation. The libraries themselves contain relocatable device code.

Comment: Thanks all for the replies, what I have tried to do since has been to compile the code in http://www.netlib.org/clapack/cblas/dtrsv.c to a device function, so far It seems to be okay, when I have finished my development I'll confirm whether it works,

Comment: It certainly [is possible](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cublas/index.html#topic_3_7) to call CUBLAS routines from device code, a new feature in CUDA 5.  I'm not sure why this answer was downvoted.  It uses the dynamic parallelism feature and therefore requires a cc 3.5 or better device.  Upvoting.  Please upvote again so we can get this off the unanswered list.